# BIOS "hangs" on Serial ATA device detection

Tags: troubleshooting, bios, sata

Some days ago I installed Windows 7 on a Fujitsu Siemens Scaleo EVi 2565 Windows Mediacenter PC (fresh installation on a new partition). The Windows 7 setup failed at the end of the installation (after one or two reboots) indicating a non specified hardware problem. To be sure I repeated the setup procedure with the same result.

I suspected a TV tuner card driver problem, so I removed the TV tuner card from the motherboard. After rebooting I got this strange behavior: the PC stops with the BIOS screen shown below.

There are a 500 GB HD and a DVD-ROM drive attached. The SATA BIOS seems to somehow recognize the two devices (see "02 Devices"), but the error says

```
Port-00: No device detected
Port-01: No device detected
```

I can't enter the BIOS settings, hitting <kbd>DEL</kbd> or function keys as usual. I also tried to remove the battery, resetting the default BIOS configuration - without luck. I'm really stuck here.

Any ideas?

[image: SATA error]

Comment: That typo ("This will take few seconds.") really bugs me. Every time I boot my machine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be caused by your faulty SATA HD. Try removing it and boot with a bootable CD to diagnose.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I was sure I did it, but appearently I didn't. :-) Now it boots from DVD. I guess that's a sign that I have to replace my 500 GB HD with a larger one. ;-)